# Azure Classic vs. New Portal: how do I assign a user to an API in the NEW portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, assign, azureportal

In the almost phasing-out Azure Classic Portal one could assign users to an API application by selecting the API from AD, then go to the tab "users", select the user and then choose the menu-item "assign".

[image]

What is the equivalent action in the new Azure Portal??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Azure Active Directory blade:

Enterprise applications > All applications > select App > Users & Groups

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-coreapps-assign-user-azure-portal

Comment: Thanks to your reference to the documentation I was able to find it out.